# Как добавить div поверх всех

Tags: css, jquery

При нажатии на `Текст` в этот div добавляется div с содержанием `Найдено 10`, но из-за того, что у `test` задана фиксированная ширина и overflow, появляется горизонтальная прокрутка, как от нее избавиться?
Если выносить `.find` за `.test` то как отловить позицию где было нажатие, чтобы добавить div рядом

Нужно, чтобы текст `Найдено 10` оставался на том же месте, но был визуально поверх `.test`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".filter").click(function() {
    $(".find").remove();
    var newElems = $("<div class='find'></div>")
      .append("Найдено 10");
    $(this).append(newElems);
  });

});
```

```css
.test {
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test .filter {
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.find {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Другой текст</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  <div class="filter">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы хотите , чтобы накладывался текст справа до границы, выходил за блок без прокрутки или как? Из вопроса не особо понятно.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Нужно, чтобы он выходил за блок без прокрутки. Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам предлагаю вот такое решение:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".filter").click(function() {
   $(".filter").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
  });

});
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".filter").click(function() {
    $(".find").remove();
    var newElems = $("<div class='find'></div>")
      .append("Найдено 10");
    $(this).append(newElems);
  });

});
```

```css
.test {
    max-height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fafafb;
}

.test .filter {
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    color: #0C0D0E;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 6px;
}
.test .filter.active {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #5fba7d;
    border: 1px solid red;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    
}
.find {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Другой текст</div></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
  <div class="filter"><div class="item">Текст</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот такое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Решил таким образом:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".filter").click(function() {
    $(".find").remove();
    
    var left = $(this).offset().left+100;//Получаем координаты элемента относительно левого верхнего угла страницы + 100px для отступа от текста
    var top = $(this).offset().top;//Получаем координаты элемента относительно верха страницы
                    
    var newElems = $("<div class='find'></div>")
      .append("Найдено 10");
    $('body').append(newElems);
    $(".find").offset({top:top, left:left});//Присваеваем полученные координаты нажатого .filter
  });

});
```

```css
.test {
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test .filter {
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.find {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Другой текст</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
    <div class="filter">Текст</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Есть только одна проблема, во втором блоке если нажать на любой `текст` и начать листать `.find` остается на месте, которое мы ему задали, возможно ли его привязать к нажатому `.filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов решения:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".filter").click(function() {
    $(".find").remove();
    var newElems = $("<li class='find'></li>")
      .append("Найдено 10");
    $(this).append(newElems);
  });

});
```

```css
.test {
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
}

.test .filter {
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: static;
}

.find {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -18px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    color: red;
}

li.filter, li.find {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test">
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Другой текст</li>
</ul>
<ul class="test">
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
  <li class="filter">Текст</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но если нажать во втором блоки на самый нижний `Текст`, то `Найдено 10` смещается вниз

Comment: @nicolaa вам именно такая конструкция нужна? что если её изменить и сделать иначе. К примеру чтобы блок появлялся прямо в самом блоке с выбором, но при этом красиво оформлено с выделением надписи? например сверху от выбранного текста или снизу.

Comment: В принципе конструкцию можно поменять, главное, чтобы текст `Найдено 10` не залазил на основной текст(на который нажали)

Comment: @nicolaa Чуть попозже сделаю. Будет как надо. Только, добавьте дополнительно в js, чтобы добавлялся класс к .filter, например «filter active», после нажатия на другую надпись, чтобы убирался с прежней и добавлялся при клики на новою. Сегодня попозже я для вас сделаю конструкцию  другую. Как сделайте, если согласны, то в комментариях сообщите мне, чтобы я знал. Ок?

Comment: Хорошо, Вам отправить js?

Comment: Достаточно тут добавить еще один, аналогичный пример с кодом, чтобы его выполнить можно было, где есть ваш обновленный код js.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1x5kq2bn/

Comment: @nicolaa Готово. В новом ответе, тут.